# How to optimize code which includes promises and for each loop when fetching data

Tags: javascript, react-native, optimization, google-cloud-firestore, promise

I have this code I have implemented, where I am fetching data. The code loops through the current users followers and grabs there information and it is all stored in state for me to use further in to the code.

The code gets messy, and I feel not efficient when I check whether the current user is following his follower. I check this by checking if the follower exists in the current users following directory.

Here is the code below:

```
// Following counts, displayname, image
  const fetchData = useCallback(() => {
    const dataRef = firestore().collection('usernames');

    dataRef
      .doc(username.toLowerCase())
      .collection('Followers')
      .limit(25)
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        // let items;
        let promises = [];
        // For each follower :
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const data = doc.data();
          promises.push(
            dataRef
              .doc(username.toLowerCase())
              .collection('Following')
              .doc(doc.id)
              .get()
              .then((docSnapshot) => {
                // If user is following this follower
                return {
                  profileName: doc.id ? doc.id : null,
                  displayName: data.displayName ? data.displayName : null,
                  followerCount:
                    data.followers !== undefined ? data.followers : 0,
                  followingCount:
                    data.following !== undefined ? data.following : 0,
                  imageUrl: data.imageUrl ? data.imageUrl : null,
                  isFollowing: docSnapshot.exists ? true : false,
                };
              }),
          );
        });
        Promise.all(promises).then((res) => setfollowersData(res));
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const dataRef = firestore().collection('usernames');

    const cleanup = dataRef
      .doc(username.toLowerCase())
      .collection('Following')
      .limit(25)
      .onSnapshot(fetchData);

    return cleanup;
  }, [username, fetchData]);
```

Comment: The code seems quite straightforward. What exactly do you think is inefficient about it? Or are you concerned about the data structures in your firestore?

Comment: I am quite new to using promises, and with fetching the data, I am having to go in to collections, while in collections. Is this normal? and is there a way to be more efficient? Thank you

Comment: Is the code correct (i.e. producing the desired results)? If so, this question should be moved to codereview.SE (which a moderator can do).

Comment: Yes the code is correct, everything works as it should